# cakephp login with or condition

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have written code for alogin.

Everything is okay but I want to add 1 more condition in our login query user_type 2 and 3 should be login only in below query. Only user_type 2 is logging.

```
$adminUser = $this->User->find("first",


array("conditions"=>array("OR"=>array(array("User.auth_key"=>$username),array("User.email"=>$username)),"User.password"=>$password,"User.user_type"=>2),
 "fields"=>array("User.idx","User.auth_key","User.email","User.first_name","User.last_name","User.profile_pic","User.user_type","User.email_activate_status","User.status","User.email_activation_code") ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with proper format and proper condition.

```
$conditions = array('OR' => array("User.auth_key"=>$username,"User.email"=>$username,"User.password"=>$password,'User.user_type' => '2','User.user_type' => '3'));
$fields = array("User.idx","User.auth_key","User.email","User.first_name","User.last_name","User.profile_pic","User.user_type","User.email_activate_status","User.status","User.email_activation_code");
$adminUser = $this->User->find("first",array("conditions"=> $conditions, "fields"=> $fields));
```